# How to Know When All Fields are Validated (Values Added) in Ant-Design Form?

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I have a simple `Form` that checks for user's input values such as name, email and address and validates them. So far I have successfully achive this. But I have a submit `button` as the last `Form.Item`  which I want to only enable when all input fields are filled and validated.

How should I check for this and subsequently set the state `formCompleted` which toggles the disabling of button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this example https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-horizontal-login.

```
function hasErrors(fieldsError) {
  return Object.keys(fieldsError).some(field => fieldsError[field]);
}

class HorizontalLoginForm extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // To disabled submit button at the beginning.
    this.props.form.validateFields();
  }

handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator, getFieldsError, getFieldError, isFieldTouched } = this.props.form;

    // Only show error after a field is touched.
    const usernameError = isFieldTouched('username') && getFieldError('username');

    return (
      <Form layout="inline" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Item validateStatus={usernameError ? 'error' : ''} help={usernameError || ''}>
          {getFieldDecorator('username', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
          })(
            <Input placeholder="Username" />,
          )}
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item>
          <Button htmlType="submit" disabled={hasErrors(getFieldsError())}>
            Log in
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

The example checks if `getFieldsError` has any values to determine if the button should be disabled or not. When the form first mounts, it uses `validateFields` to validate your inputs and updates `getFieldsError`. The problem with this is that errors will show before any inputs happen which is why it then checks if the fields have been touched before before it shows the errors using `isFieldTouched`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hah...Lol why I didn't look the very first example in docs!? Silly me ;p Thanks @John Wong, btw

Comment: It works great but what if I have to also include a checkbox as form item and when it is checked to only then enable the submit button, it does't work. See my code: `const agreementError = isFieldTouched('ag') && getFieldError('ag') <Form.Item validateStatus={agreementError ? 'error' : ''} help={agreementError || ''}>
          {getFieldDecorator('ag', {
              rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please check it!' }],
              valuePropName: 'checked',
              initialValue: false,
            })(<Checkbox>I've read the T&C</Checkbox>)}
        </Form.Item>`

Comment: Never mind. Made it to work after setting type to boolean and using custom validator

Comment: Just saw your answer. Don't know if we ended up with the same answer but this was the answer I found https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/8261#issuecomment-439833733.

Also, you could also just check your checkbox value in the Button disabled prop ```<Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" disabled={hasErrors(getFieldsError()) || !getFieldValue("ag")}>```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks John. Appreciated your help!